# pgsql query result separated with comma

Tags: php, postgresql

My Database
Table // Name : accounts

```
id | login | password | macaddress
1  | ab    | ex       | 2X:D0:5X:5E:77:CX
2  | ac    | example  | 2X:D0:5X:5E:77:CX
3  | ad    | example  | 5X:Y0:GX:FE:27:G8
```

The query

```
$sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM accounts where macaddress = '2X:D0:5X:5E:77:CX' ")
while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql) )
echo "$row[id]";
```

The Result : 12

What result i want is : 1,2

I hope u can help me solve this.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in an array first and join them.

```
$array = [];

$sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM accounts where macaddress = '2X:D0:5X:5E:77:CX' ")
while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql) )
$array[] = $row[id];

echo join(',', $array);
```